# Showing equality of expectation

Tags: probability-theory

$X$ is a random variable, $Y=bX, b\neq 0 $. I want to show that $E[XY]=\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)$.

My attempt, $$\begin{align}E[XY]&=E[X\cdot bX] \\&=bE[X^2]\\&=b(Var(X)-E[X]^2)\\&=b(\sigma(X)^{2} -E[X]^2)\\&=\sigma(Y)\sigma(X)-bE[X^2].\end{align}$$

Not sure how to continue...

Comment: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ so $E(X^2) = Var(X) + E(X)^2$

Comment: Oh yeah the sign should be positive then, but how do I continue?

Comment: How did you finally answer the exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b=1$. You know

$$E[X^2] = Var(X) - E[X]^2 = \sigma(X)\sigma(X) - E[X]^2$$

Why would you generally expect for $E[X]^2$ to equal $0$? I think you must also assume that $X$ has mean zero.

Comment: There were no further assumptions stated on the exercise, so not sure if I can do that..

Answer (score 0):

May be an Idea-

Let us consider correlation coefficient $\rho = \frac{E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$

so that $\rho = \frac{b E(X^2) - b E(X)^2}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}  = \frac{b Var(X)}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$,

Since $X$ and $Y$ are related so $\rho = 1$ , so $bVar(X) = \sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}$

**EDIT-**

also if $b<0$ then $\rho=-1$,$bVar(X)=-\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}$

Also note that 
$\sigma_{y} = b \sigma_{x}$
So if your result is true that is if $E(XY) = \sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}$,

Then $bE(X^2) = b \sigma_{x}^2$

$E(X^2) = \sigma_{x}^2 = Var(X)$

Now if you see the above only holds when $E(X) = 0$!

Comment: Will $\rho=1$? Since we dont know if $b$>0 or $b<0$ ? Couldnt it be -1 also?

Comment: Yes! just did an edit!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a nice solution, you can say:

"I believe the exercise is ill-posed. Here is a counter-example. Let $X$ be a constant random variable equal to 1, let $b=1$ and let $Y=bX$. Then $E[XY]=1$ but $\sigma(X)\sigma(Y)=0$. So I will provide a proof under the further assumption that $EX=0$." [then you continue with what you wrote]